# jquery issue : any css changes before an each loop apply only after

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some code like following :

```
LoadingImage.show("#contentpage", urlStk.LoadImg);

var errors = 0;
var ComponentToUpdate = new Array();
var storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Components"));

$(".myDataGridRow").each(function () {
    errors += validateInput(this);
    component = {
       FamilyCode: $.trim($("td[name=FamilyCode]", this).text())
    }
    ComponentToUpdate.push(component);
});
LoadingImage.hide("#contentpage");
```

The `$(".myDataGridRow").each())` loop can be a little bit slow. So I try to display some waiting animated gif that overlays on the data grid and its rows `(myDataGridRow)`.

`LoadingImage.show()` and `LoadingImage.hide()` methods do work fine when the executed code between is some ajax call to a remote server.

The problem is that the animated gif never appears in this case (the each() loop is only going through HTML elements and performing simpls validations), nor its parent DIV container...

After many tests, it seems that any javascript code written before the each() loop seems to be executed after (I have not tried the alert() case, but any css changes on other elements are blocked till the each() loop finishes, timers declared before are triggered after... ) ??

Forcing the display of the waiting image inside the each loop does not work.

Any help idea will be welcome.

Comment: wrap the code after the 1st line in a small anon function inside a setTimeout for 10ms...

Comment: Thanks. There's sth in the code that prevents the animation to appear before the each (the animation itself is using a simple divID.fadeIn()). I tried many things: postponing the loop by using setTimeout() or $.Differ(), executing the each on the complete of the fadeIn(), or dequeue() all effects on all elements... It works when I interrupt or preceed the each loop by using alert("") : in this case jquery seems to take all waiting effects to really execute, but this is not very user friendly... Last way perhaps : using web workers... Thanks again. –

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, your animation isn't playing because the JavaScript is running in the main thread. If you use `setTimeout()` or `setImmediate()`, you can run your expensive code in a separate thread, which will allow the browser itself to handle displaying the animation.

Example below:

```
LoadingImage.show("#contentpage", urlStk.LoadImg);

setImmediate(function () {
    var errors = 0;
    var ComponentToUpdate = new Array();
    var storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Components"));

    $(".myDataGridRow").each(function () {
        errors += validateInput(this);
        component = {
            FamilyCode: $.trim($("td[name=FamilyCode]", this).text())
        }
        ComponentToUpdate.push(component);
    });

    LoadingImage.hide("#contentpage");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. There's sth in the code that prevents the animation to appear before the each (the animation itself is using a simple divID.fadeIn()).
I tried many things: postponing the loop by using setTimeout() or $.Differ(), executing the each on the complete of the fadeIn(), or dequeue() all effects on all elements...
It works when I interrupt or preceed the each loop by using alert("") : in this case jquery seems to take all waiting effects to really execute, but this is not very user friendly...
Last way perhaps : using web workers...
Thanks again.